# How do I retrieve all data from an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I used this code for retrieving specific value from the XML file.Now i want to retrieve all the data which are present in the XML file .Can anybody help me to find out the solution?

```
StorageFile xmlFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Content1.xml");
XmlDocument xmlDoc;
xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile);
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());

var query=
    from Date in duc.Root.Elements("Serial")
    where Date.Attribute("No").Value=="1"
    from Current in Date.Elements("Current")
    select new {
        NarratedBy=Current.Attribute("NarratedBy").Value,
        value=Current.Attribute("Date").Value
    };

foreach(var Date in query) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value);
}
```

Comment: inside the for each loop what should i have to change to retrieve more than two value/data?

Answer (score 1):

You already have whole XML document loaded into `duc` variable.

That line is responsible for that:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());
```

Comment: inside the foreach loop i used the condition to display some specific data and now i want to display all data which are present in xml document..

Comment: use `duc.ToString()`. You're querying document, not changing it.

Comment: In my xml file i have 2 blocks for example <t1> and <t2> ..i declared some attributes inside both blocks..now i want to retrieve all the data which i declared in <t1>.so what should i have to do?

Comment: consider the above question ..in that i retrieved the value of narratedby and date ..In my xml i have 5 value Narratedby,ArabicDate,EnglishDate,HadithBody,ReferencedBy..now i want to retrieve all the values.so what should i have to do?

Comment: inside the foreach loop previously i used xmltextblock.text=("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value)+Environment.NewLine;

Answer (score 0):

then you can just retrieve your `XDocument` details for example into a `string` variable with an XDocument extension [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.tostring.aspx)

Comment: In my xml file i have 2 blocks for example <t1> and <t2> ..i declared some attributes inside both blocks..now i want to retrieve  all the data which i declared in <t1>.so what should i have to do?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question (or edit it as well). Put some example and clearly tell what you want to do.

Comment: consider the above question ..in that i retrieved the value of narratedby and date ..In my xml i have 5 value Narratedby,ArabicDate,EnglishDate,HadithBody,ReferencedBy..now i want to retrieve all the values.so what should i have to do?

Comment: inside the foreach loop previously i used xmltextblock.text=("{0}\t{1}", Date.NarratedBy, Date.value)+Environment.NewLine;

Answer (score 0):

You have all data already:

```
xmlDoc = await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(xmlFile); // data loadded
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument duc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml()); // data parsed
```

===================

Here is a sample code how you may do it. It is fully functional (using local string xml instead of your file) so you may run it. I added only three attributes but you may add as many as you want.

```
class Program {
static void Main(string[] args) {
// this is a sample string. Use your file instead
string s = "<catalog>" +
"<book id=\"bk101\" author=\"Gambardella, Matthew\" title=\"XML Developer's Guide\" genre=\"Computer\"/>" +
"<book id=\"bk102\" author=\"Ralls, Kim\" title=\"Midnight Rain\" genre=\"Fantasy\"/>" +
"</catalog>";

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(s); // here we load data
// here we get attributes. I have three, you will add three more. Also you may want to use string array instead of variables
            foreach (XmlNode task in xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
                string author = task.Attributes["author"].InnerText;
                string title = task.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
                string genre = task.Attributes["genre"].InnerText;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have 6 attributes in my xml file and have 6 textblocks,i want to display each attribute in different textblocks.what is the code used for that?